# Journey Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data, data-views

I just wanted to ask, if I have a journey that was created 6 months back, but I created a new version of the journey within 6 months, will the data view of journey give me the data for this journey or no?. I know that data views don't store the data for more than 6 months. But wanted to check on this scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes assuming the new version is within the 6 month window.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for your reply, but I raised a case with Salesforce, and they say it won't give. Also, I was testing something and i couldn't see the journey

Answer (score 0):

Typically only event-based data views that accumulate lots of records have this 6 month retention. _Job and _Subscribers for example, retain all data.

From my testing the _Journey data view retains all data too, so you would be fine in this scenario.